# Unchecked casts and unnecessary suppressed warnings with lambdas

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, java-8, compiler-warnings

While working with Lambdas and generics, I encountered a special case of unsafe cast warnings.

During reproducing and making an SSCCE, I found that it is probably related to the fact that the lambda is effectively "inside" the return statement.

The question is: **Why do I get a warning in the `warningUnnecessarySuppressWarnings` method?**. When *removing* `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`, I get:

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from List to List

As shown in the `warningUnsafeCast` method. Because of this, the annotation is not unnecessary as the new warning says.

I am using Eclipse Kepler SP2 for Java EE Developers, with Build id: 20140224-0627

Also using [the recommended](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler) update-site for [Java 8 support in Eclipse Kepler](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3-P-builds/)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(warningUnnecessarySuppressWarnings());
    System.out.println(warningUnsafeCast());
    System.out.println(withoutWarning());
}

private static Integer perform(Function<List<?>, Integer> func) {
    return func.apply(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
}

private static Integer warningUnnecessarySuppressWarnings() {
    return perform(list -> {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // Unnecessary @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<String> unsafeCast = (List<String>) list;
        return unsafeCast.size();
    });
}

private static Integer warningUnsafeCast() {
    return perform(list -> {
        List<String> unsafeCast = (List<String>) list; // Type safety: Unchecked cast from List<capture#4-of ?> to List<String>
        return unsafeCast.size();
    });
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static Integer withoutWarning() {
    return perform(list -> {
        List<String> unsafeCast = (List<String>) list;
        return unsafeCast.size();
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't get the `Unnecessary @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` with javac in your `warningUnnecessarySuppressWarnings` method. Maybe an eclipse issue?

Comment: You are assigning a `List<?>` to a `List<String>`. Why shouldn't that cause a warning? If you replace the wildcard in `perform` with a type parameter, all warnings will disappear.

Comment: @nosid I am fully aware of what I am doing, the question is why I get the **`Unnecessary @SuppressWarnings`** warning when in fact, the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation is not unnecessary at all. This code is an SSCCE, this is of course not my actual code!

Comment: @assylias I had the feeling it might be an Eclipse issue. (which is why I added the `eclipse` tag)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg If it interests you at all, I've experienced similar "unnecessary `@SuppressWarnings`" warnings when working with Eclipse's null annotations. Sounds to me like it's an Eclipse bug too. I filed a bug a bit back, but made the unfortunate decision of including another bug with it, so the "unnecessary `@SuppressWarnings`" thing never got fixed. If you submit a bug report, mind sharing a link to the report?

Comment: I get this message, too, and it's definitely a bug. I suggest disabling the "unnecessary @SuppressWarning" warning in Eclipse compiler's configuration.

Comment: Time for a `@SuppressUnnecessaryWarningsAboutSuppressWarnings` annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in question is type-unsafe and therefore should generate a warning. The `@SuppressWarnings` annotation is of course necessary to suppress this warning.

It is apparently a bug in Eclipse Kepler SP2 that it issues a warning for the statement, but then warns that `@SuppressWarnings` is unnecessary when the annotation is added.

The workaround is to disable the "unnecessary `@SuppressWarning`" warning in the Eclipse compiler configuration.